# Where to put login logging method to capture userid in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to create a record every time someone logs in, but I'm having an issue with capturing the userid during the login post.  Here is the standard login POST.  I've added in my LoginSysAction below the signin success.  However my userid is null.

```
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                await LoginSysAction();
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

Here is my logging method:

```
    private async Task LoginSysAction()
    {
        var addSysAction = new SysAction();
        addSysAction.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        addSysAction.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        addSysAction.ActionType = "Login";
        db.SysActions.Add(addSysAction);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So my question is basically - is GetUserId() unavailable to me at this point?  And if not, what would be the best method to achieve something similar?

Comment: Check your namespaces for `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

Comment: It's in there.  I think it has to do with when the userid is known, but I felt like at this point in the login process it would be there.

Answer (score 0):

`GetUserId()` is not available during this controller action. Nor is `GetUserName`, or probably any of the other Identity methods (though I haven't tried them). I was also surprised that they weren't available!

You can, however, lookup the user id using `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync()` which returns an `ApplicationUser`, which inherits from the `IdentityUser`. Since you know the email that was just used to successfully log in, just look up the user.

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    var justLoggedIn = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    await LoginSysAction(justLoggedIn.Id);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Obviously, you'd need change your `LoginSysAction` a bit to accommodate this.

It's not exactly efficient, though, doing repeated db calls, so it might be worth incorporating the userid lookup into your actual database query that stores the login information.

A nicer place to do the logging might be in `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` which you can override.

```
public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    if (UserManager == null)
        return SignInStatus.Failure;

    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if (user == null)
        return SignInStatus.Failure;

    if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
        return SignInStatus.LockedOut;

    if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
    {
        await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, false);
        // put your logging here!
        await LoginSysAction(user.Id);
        return SignInStatus.Success;
    }

    if (shouldLockout)
    {
        await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
        if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
    }

    return SignInStatus.Failure;
}
```